# Error while registering a new jquery API function (in Ruby on Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I tried adding https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit to my Rails application. The code in https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEditworks works perfectly as standalone; but when I include celledit.js inside my Rails application, i get this error in my broswer development console:

```
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined
```

While the same code works fine in standalone application, why am I getting this error in Ruby on Rails app? What does this error mean? And how do I resolve it?

NOTE:

The error is coming from the function definition shown below:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('MakeCellsEditable()', function (settings) {
   var table = this.table();

   jQuery.fn.extend({
```

Comment: it looks like like you are registering the plugin before `Datatable` is actually loaded. Have you tried putting this code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` ?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed - Should I use what you suggested instead of calling jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register?

Comment: Np, Just replace the the `...` in my example with your code or just check where are you initializing the datatable with something like `$('#myTable').DataTable();` and register the Api after that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery rails gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
```

Run `run bundle install`.

Then include the dependencies in the correct order in your `app/assets/javascripts.js`:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require dataTables.cellEdit
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

In this case I just downloaded the files and placed them in `app/assets/javascripts`.

If you are using Turbolinks you want to hook the initialisation onto the `turbolinks:load` event as `document.ready` only happens on the initial page load:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require dataTables.cellEdit
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

  function myCallbackFunction (updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
      console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
      console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
  }

  table.MakeCellsEditable({
      "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
  });
});
```

If you are not using Turbolinks then just use `jQuery.ready(function(){...})` instead of `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){});`.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I tried what you suggested; I see this error now: `couldn't find file 'jquery.dataTables.min' with type 'application/javascript'`